# Angular schema form + highlight fields with errors on form load

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I am using angular schema form. The problem I have is, when I try to load the form there are some required attributes which are missing! The form doesn`t indicate about the missing properties. But when I click on that particular field and edit something and then remove it, it does show highlight the field for me. I want this to happen at initial loading as well. Looking for pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **required** property in your form config schema:

```
//..other fields
"required": [
    "name",
    "email",
    "comment"
  ]
```

Check the [demo here](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html), it has required fields as well:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "name":  {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },//here validation details
    "email":  {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
      "description": "Email will be used for evil."
    },
    "comment": {
      "title": "Comment",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 20,
      "validationMessage": "Don't be greedy!"
    }
  },//here naming fields required
  "required": ["name","email","comment"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property is `validateOnRender: true`

It needs to be added to the form's [global options object](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#global-options).